# Does venturi effect violate pascal's law?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

[image]
If we use Bernouill's law to compare pressure between point 1 and point 2, we find that P(2)gdH=0, we conclute P(2)=P(1).
I must have made a mistake but where is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pascal's law is applicable to hydrostatics, Venturi effect - to hydrodynamics.

Comment: Ok thank you, so pascal's law is only applicable to fluid at rest, and benouilli's law to fluid on motion(only or both?)

Comment: @MaickelTawdrous Fluid in motion only - for Venturi effect. Bernoulli's law holds for fluids at rest, but it does not add much value there.